# Apache2 do not use dash as character representing null, but just empty string

Tags: apache-2.4

I defined a custom log for my Apache server, where I log some headers. I've noticed that Apache instead of just using an empty string, it logs non-existent values as "-" dash. I understand why that is, but is there a way to avoid that behaviour and log null values as empty strings?

For example `\"_http_referer\": \"%{Referer}i\"` turns into `\"_http_referer\": \"-\"` when the `Referrer` header is not set, I need it to be `\"_http_referer\": \"\"`

Comment: If apache were to use an empty string then the tools that access the logs would break, they would be unable to determine which field is which. If that is something you really want, then send it via syslog and use a regex to delete them before they reach storage.